# Regex to match beginning and end of line in Vim (quote around whole line)

Tags: text-processing, vim, regular-expression

For an initial file with lines like this example:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

The desired state of the file is

```
'1'
'12'
'123'
'1234'
'12345'
```

I've been doing this with two commands, `:%s/^/'/g` and `:%s/$/'/g`, that I would like to get into one.  However, when I try

```
:%s/[$^]/'/g
```

I get the error

```
E486: Pattern not found: [$^]
```

I know the leading `^` in brackets means exclusion, so I figured putting `$` first would mean match both the beginning and end of lines, which is obviously not happening.

How can I match both the beginning and end of lines in vim?

Comment: _Avoid answering questions in comments._

Comment: `%norm I'<c-v><esc>A'`

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please use the checkmark to tell the system that the question is Answered. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller, Aye, and thanks for following up. I'd like to give the community a few more days to provide answers before selecting the problem as solved, but I won't forget to follow through.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
:%s/.*/'&'/
```

"Replace zero or more characters with those characters preceded and succeded by a single-quote".

Answer (score 5):

`^` and `$` do not hold those meanings (start or end of line) inside `[ ]`, which is used for selecting a group of characters. Inside `[ ]`, most regex operators lose their meaning (and some characters gain special meaning, or get a different meaning). A leading `^` in `[]` means that the group is negated - match everything *except* these characters. So `[^$]` matches on any character other than `$`. (And `[$^]` matches just the `$` and `^` characters.)

If you want to match the start *or* end of a line, use `/^\|$/`, where `|` is *or* (needs to be escaped in Vim's default regex mode).

So:

```
:%s/^\|$/'/g
```

The `g` is needed since the `^` and `$` are two independent matches, and `s` by default only acts on the first match in a line.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to match the beginning and end of the line if you can just greedily match the whole thing:

```
:%s/\(.*\)/'\1'/
```

The main thing to know is to escape the parenthesis to create the "capture group", then use `\1` to refer back to what was captured.

Comment: Seems like a harder version of the accepted answer's `%s/.*/'&'/g` but maybe more extensible if there are several matching groups.

Answer (score 1):

With `norm[al]` command and `A` to append control, `I` to prepend control which we make the `:exe[cute]` command to execute the second prepend 'norm' since by default `:norm[al]`command cannot be followed by another command as in `:help :normal` documented.

so the command would be as below:

```
:exe "%norm A'" |%norm I'
```

Note that `%` here performing the changes on all lines.

Comment: Neat option.  Not exactly a regex but it gets the job done in vim.